# Python is not showing floating decimals correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python2.7 installed on ubuntu 16.04. It's showing strange behavior. If I check for (5/4), it will just display 1 as output.

for (6/7) it is showing 0

Can anyone help me to fix this?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Comment: for (6/7) I expected .8571
for (5/4) I expected 1.25

Comment: Try `float(8)/65`

Comment: Python **2** used integer division: integers in → integers out. Use floats to to do floating point math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a strange error at all. Python 2.7 does **Integer** division, so you will always get an integers as the result of the expressions you have named. You can view it this way if you want:

5/4=int(5/4)=int(1.25) = 1

And this is how you can understand the expression you have shown:

float(5/4)= float(int(5/4)) = float(1) = 1.0

you need to use floats:

```
5.0/4.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much